# Windows failover cluster - Delegate permissions to Domain user to move a group to another node

Tags: windows-server-2008, cluster, windows-server-2012, failovercluster, windows-cluster

Is it somehow possible to assign permisions to non-admin user to monitor and move cluster group? Is there any workaround for this? I'm interested in Windows server 2008 r2 and 2012.

I'm avare there is read-only access for monitoring from Windows Server 2008.

Comment: Are you using System Center 2012 Virtual Machine Manager?  If so, you should be able to setup the Self Service Portal to enable this.

Comment: Thanks. But this also gives full admin permissions on Cluster? I need to restrict user to only one resource group.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could write 2 scripts: one to view information about the specific resource group and one to [move the group](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee461002.aspx). Then delegate rights to non-admin users to execute those scripts against the cluster(s) using [System Frontier](http://systemfrontier.com). The user won't have to have any rights on the server. Full disclosure... I own the company that makes System Frontier.